# Null check in Linq query expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a working method-based query that looks like this:

```
string param = request.QRBarang.Split('~')[1];
var a = await _db.A.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.IdA == param);
var b = await _db.B.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.IdB1 == a.IdA);
var c = await _db.C.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.IdC1 == b.IdB2);
var d = c != null
         ? await _db.D.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => d.IdD == c.IdC2)
         : null;
var dto = new DTOFin { ...};
```

I'm still learning LINQ and trying to convert the syntax into query expression, but always get error when the value of c is null.
Here's my try:

```
var dto = (from a in _db.A
           join b in _db.B on a.IdA equals b.IdB1
           join c in _db.C on b.IdB2 equals c.IdC1
           join d in _db.D on c.IdC2 equals d.IdD
           where a.IdA == param && object.Equals(c.IdC2, d.IdD)
           select new DTOFin { ...}).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I also tried using `join c in _db.C on b.IdB2 equals c?.IdC1` but produced

> Error CS8072  An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.

How should I write the first syntax equivalent in query expression?

Comment: You need to use left join syntax in LINQ/

Comment: Your also need to `await` all `Async` Linq methods. Entity Framework does not support concurrent queries, so your code should be like `var a = await _db.A.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.IdA == param);`.

Comment: Will try that, @Chetan.
I actually used `await` but somehow missed that when writing the question @Dai

Comment: I assume this is EF Core? Do you not have any navigation properties in your model?

Comment: Agree with Jeremy - you do seem to be making your life awfully hard work compared to being able to say eg `context.Employees.Where(e => e.Department.Manager.LengthOfService > 10)` to find all employees working for a manager who has served longer than 10 years

Comment: @BillyJoseph Please do not edit your post with the possible solution for your problem. Please leave a new post and if you are fine with that then mark it as the answer.

Comment: @BillyJoseph EF Core is an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. JOINs are generated by the ORM itself based on the relations and navigation properties between entities. If you have an `Order` class with a `Customer`, querying for `Order` will bring back `Customer` as well if needed. You only have to write `o=>o.Customer` in some expression and EF will generate either JOINs or separate queries as needed. If you have to use JOINs like this, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @BillyJoseph and no, that Left Join isn't a solution. The solution is to use proper relations so you can write nothing more than `_db.A.Select(a=>new DTO{ MyB=a.B, MyCs=a.C.ToArrray()});`

Comment: @Dai "Entity Framework does not support concurrent queries" - Not true: it does, only not all *db providers* support it. If you know that your provider has support (and that it will not change to one that doesn't) then you can enable it by adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to the connection string, and then write EF code that uses it.

Comment: I will need to take a look into that first, @JeremyLakeman... It's a query to get the history of a Stock Keeping Unit and track its current location. I have to get the data from various tables. I didn't design the database, I'm the UI guy that for some reasons have to learn the backend programming by himself.

Comment: @PeterB `MultipleActiveResultSets` is specific to SQL Server and is unrelated to Entity Framework. As far as I know (at least as of November 2020, and EF Core 3.1) you cannot have concurrent operations on a single `DbContext`; I understand the closest thing to concurrent queries is to create a temporary new separate `DbContext` _for each query_ (and then `await Task.WhenAll` all queries) and if your queries were getting entities then you need to detach them from the temporary `DbContext` then reattach them to the main `DbContext`). As far as I know this hasn't changed in EF Core 5 either.

Comment: @BillyJoseph Even if you didn't design the database, you can still add navigation-properties and even _lie_ to EF and make it believe that foreign-key constraints exist when they're not in the actual database (this is how you can make EF support database `VIEW`s as normal entity tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have Navigation Properties configured correctly then this should work:

(I note that EF6 and EF Core's scaffolding templates (for auto-generating entity classes from an existing database) do this for you already.)

(Also, I really don't like C#'s keyword-style Linq expressions because in order to do almost anything you need to tack-on Linq extension-methods, which clashes aesthetically with keyword-style expressions. I can't think of any good reason to use keyword-style Linq expressions thesedays, honestly).

I assume `_db` is your `DbContext`.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity; // for EF6
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query; // for EF Core

A a = await _db.A
    .Include( a => a.B )
    .Include( a => a.B.C )
    .Include( a => a.B.C.D )
    .Where( a => a.IdA == param )
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

// b, c, and d can then be gotten from A:
B b = a.B;
C c = a.B.C;
D d = a.B.C?.D; // It looks like A.B and B.C are INNER JOIN while C.D is LEFT OUTER JOIN. Linq will use the correct JOIN type (INNER, LEFT, etc) based on your model configuration. You cannot tell from the query alone.

return new DTOFin() { ... };
```

---

If you *don't* have navigation properties set-up (and you should...) then you can do Joins manually - but it is noticably *more gnarly* because Linq's `.Join` method was never intended to be used directly because you're expected to use Navigation Properties instead.

- Note that because this Linq query is being used with Entity Framework it means your query must be representable in SQL...

  - Which it means that certain limitations apply: such as not using the `?.` operator - which is your issue.
  - Other limitations include not being able to use your own custom predicate functions (unless they're also `Expression<Func<>>`) because you can't just put C# code into a SQL query.

I believe the below query *should* work, but I cannot say for certain without knowing more about your EF model configuration and database design - you haven't provided enough detail in your opening question post.

```
var a_b_c_d = await _db.A
    .Join( _db.B, a     => a.IdA       , b => b.IdB1, ( a    , b ) => new { a, b } )
    .Join( _db.C, a_b   => a_b.b.IdB2  , c => c.IdC1, ( a_b  , c ) => new { a_b.a, a_b.b, c } )
    .Join( _db.D, a_b_c => a_b_c.c.IdC2, d => d.IdD , ( a_b_c, d ) => new { a_b_c.a, a_b_c.b, a_b_c.c, d } )
    .Where( a_b_c_d => a_b_c_d.a.IdA == param )
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

A a = a_b_c_d.a;
B b = a_b_c_d.b;
C c = a_b_c_d.c;
D d = a_b_c_d.d;

return new DTOFin() { ... };
```

Comment: Need to learn lots before I completely figure this out, but I think you gave me enough to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work by using LINQ query syntax.

```
    var dto = (from a in _db.A
               join b in _db.B on a.IdA equals b.IdB1
               join c in _db.C on b.IdB2 equals c.IdC1 into cTemp
               from cT in cTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join d in _db.D on c.IdC2 equals d.IdD into dTemp
               from dT in dTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where a.IdA == param
               select new DTOFin 
               {
               ...
               }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

you can select c and d table values from cT and dT variables.